# Change language of the title of the plugin in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

[image]

I want to change the value of the title "Emoji List" as per the lang. say french, it is coming from fr.js

How to modify the language values

```
CKEDITOR.lang['fr']['emoji']['title'] = 'abcd';
```

I was doing this,

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceLoaded', function(evt) {
  CKEDITOR.lang['fr']['emoji']['title'] = 'abcd';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have checked the Emoji plugin only has the English translation: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major/plugins/emoji/lang.

If you want to add French language manually to that plugin, here is how:

1. Download CKEditor repo from Github - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev
2. Go to https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major/plugins/emoji/lang and copy-paste `en.js` file
3. Rename it to `fr.js`
4. Open `fr.js`, change the language code in `CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang( 'emoji', 'en', {` to `fr` and change all the translations of `key:translation` pairs from English to French (please remember to leave the keys untouched).
5. Go to https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/emoji/plugin.js#L548 and change `lang: 'en',` to `lang: 'en,fr',`.
6. Once this is done, you can build your own editor instance - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_build.html

If you would like to also help the community, you can join the CKEditor translation center and provide your translations there: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_uilanguage.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't want to change the language, rather I want to support multiple languages. And I dont want to modify existing language files provided by plugin

Comment: In order to support multiple languages, you need to support multiple language files. You are not modifying existing language files. You are adding a new one based on the copy of old one (you use it as a template). The only thing you modify is the language code inside the plugin file. Unfortunately there is no other way to do it if you want to support localization/multiple language files. This is how CKEditor works.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, I can use the load function provided `CKEDITOR` like this:-

```
CKEDITOR.lang.load('fr', 'en', (languageCode, json) => {
  json['emoji']['title'] = 'My Custom title';
});
```